# Compiling STK (Synthesis Toolkit) for use in Code::Blocks

Tags: audio, linker, undefined-reference

I realise this is a newb question but I've been racking my brains for hours.
So I want to use the STK (Synthesis Toolkit) to generate sine waves etc.  I've downloaded the source files from https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/download.html
I unzipped the tar.gz using 7zip.
I opened up the demo.cpp project file (under /projects/demo/demo.cpp) and whenever I try to compile it, I receive lots of errors, all starting with "undefined reference to"
I have set the compiler search directory to include the root folder of the stk kit (unzipped as "stk-4.5.0").  My understanding is that I also have to find file for the linker, that is of the type .lib? Is that correct? I haven't been able to find a .lib file to link to.
I feel like this is a simple fix - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You've downloaded a source , not the compiled library which might be used by linker (.lib file) There are three solutions:
1. Compile whole src folder of your download ( see instructions on their  website). Frankly, I've tried to do that recently but failed, especially under Windows although I don't have any experience in this so you can try yourself.
2. Use precompiled library available in some Linux repositories. I had success with Slacko Puppy linux. Package simply adds libstk.a (linux static library) to /usr/lib and stk headers  to /usr/include/stk (notice you have to add exactly that path to compiler, since /usr/lib is not enough). This gave me best results.
3. If you use only several classes, you can copy their .cpp files directly to your project source folder. Remember to add parent classes, too (see STK site -> Classes). Again I recommend that you give the compiler path to include folder you've unzipped, but copying only selected headers should also work.
I've found this article helpful (see also A1): http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/

Hope I've helped